# Python - For loop for listing the count of number in list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, count

I have a list of random numbers in no specific order. Is there a way to count the number of times each number can be found in the list, and create a new list with these counts using a for loop? So not using an existing Python function.
So, for example I have the list [9,18,13,9,6,6,16,6,17,10,15,16,13,11,13,8,20,6,18,11].
The output I want to have is [2,2,3,2,4 etc.].

A code I currently have is:

```
def countlisting(numberlist):
    the_count = 0
    q = 0
    listofcount = []
    for i in range(len(numberlist)):
        if numberlist[i] == numberlist[q]:
            the_count += 1
            listofcount.append(the_count)
            q += 1
    return listofcount

the_numberlist = [9,18,13,9,6,6,16,6,17,10,15,16,13,11,13,8,20,6,18,11]
print(countlisting(the_numberlist))
```

Comment: Without any imports: `print([the_numberlist.count(value) for value in the_numberlist])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum=0
list1=[]
the_numberlist = [9,18,13,9,6,6,16,6,17,10,15,16,13,11,13,8,20,6,18,11]
for i in range(len(the_numberlist)):
    for j in range(len(the_numberlist)):
        if the_numberlist[0]==the_numberlist[j]:
         sum+=1
    if len(the_numberlist)!=0:
      remove_element=the_numberlist[0]
    else:
        break
    while remove_element in the_numberlist:
        the_numberlist.remove(remove_element)
    list1.append(sum)
    sum=0
print(list1)
```

#output: [2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

I did my best for don`t use the function

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```py
from collections import Counter

the_numberlist = [9,18,13,9,6,6,16,6,17,10,15,16,13,11,13,8,20,6,18,11]
c = Counter(the_numberlist)
print(list(c.values()))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and get values from `dict` like below:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> the_numberlist = [9,18,13,9,6,6,16,6,17,10,15,16,13,11,13,8,20,6,18,11]
>>> list(Counter(the_numberlist).values())
[2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]



# for more explanation
>>> Counter(the_numberlist)
Counter({9: 2,
         18: 2,
         13: 3,
         6: 4,
         16: 2,
         17: 1,
         10: 1,
         15: 1,
         11: 2,
         8: 1,
         20: 1})
```

You can implement this counter yourself

```
>>> dct_cnt = {}
>>> for num in the_numberlist:
...    dct_cnt[num] = dct_cnt.get(num, 0) + 1
    
>>> dct_cnt
{9: 2, 18: 2, 13: 3, 6: 4, 16: 2, 17: 1, 10: 1, 15: 1, 11: 2, 8: 1, 20: 1}

>>> list(dct_cnt.values())
[2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```